# Access the changes files in git pre-receive hook & search for string pattern

Tags: bash, git, unix, github

I have one pre-commit script/hook working just fine to search for specific string pattern in the files and reject the commit. I'm not sure how to read the incoming files in the pre-receive script to search for  string pattern.

My pre-commit scripts looks like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if git rev-parse --verify HEAD >/dev/null 2>&1
then
    against=HEAD
else
    # Initial commit: diff against an empty tree object
    EMPTY_TREE=$(git hash-object -t tree /dev/null)
    against=$EMPTY_TREE
fi

FILES=$(git diff --cached --name-only $against)

if [ -n "$FILES" ]; then

string1 = $(grep -rE --line-number 'access_key' $FILES)

   if [ -n "$string1" ] then
            echo "string1 there so reject it"
        while true; do
                exit 1;

         done
  fi
fi
```

I'm not sure how to convert this to a pre-receive hook script on git server side.
I've been trying this for hours with no luck. Can someone please help me out here?

Comment: What do you expect to happen that doesn't happen as you expect, why do you expect it, and what happens instead?  The docs you from `git help hooks` are pretty comprehensive.

Comment: i am expecting any keys referenced  in the files and if so pre-receive hook needs to reject the imcoming push ( Ex: like  user credentials keys of public keys   acccess_key & secret_key kind of strings ).

Comment: I think let me rephrase  of my question  - Need help to get access the changed files  in git pre-receive hook